# What are the symbolisms associated with the fingers of the hands?

Tags: identification-request, yoga, symbolism

I read somewhere recently that with your palm facing you and going clockwise (anti-clockwise if left hand), starting from the middle finger, the *Panchabhuta* in order of creation are represented. To be clear, this implies

- **Middle Finger - Akasha**
- **Index Finger - Vayu**
- **Thumb - agni**
- **Little Finger - Ap**
- **Ring Finger - Prithvi**

Is this enumeration correct? Which sources, if any, speak of this?